# How to create a nested x-axis level xy chart using Achartengine

Tags: android, achartengine

[image]In my app I want to create a time distance xy line chart using achartengine. So in x-axis I want to show the levels in months at first. Then after zooming the levels has to convert day. There should be pinch to zoom functionality which should change graph from Month to Week and then on further zooming to days. So any ideas? Any links or any suggestion will appreciated. This is my class..
 `package com.atos.graphreq;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.List;

import org.achartengine.ChartFactory;
import org.achartengine.GraphicalView;
import org.achartengine.model.XYMultipleSeriesDataset;
import org.achartengine.model.XYSeries;
import org.achartengine.renderer.XYMultipleSeriesRenderer;
import org.achartengine.renderer.XYSeriesRenderer;
import org.achartengine.renderer.XYSeriesRenderer.FillOutsideLine;
import org.achartengine.tools.PanListener;
import org.achartengine.tools.ZoomEvent;
import org.achartengine.tools.ZoomListener;

import com.atos.graphreq.R;
import com.atos.graphreq.database.Database;
import com.atos.graphreq.model.AppZoyDebug;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint.Align;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams;

public class GraphActivity extends Activity {
    private GraphicalView mChartView;

```
XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer;
List<Double> xValues;
List<Double> yValues;
LinearLayout layout;
Database db;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.graphlayout);
    db = new Database(this);
    db.open();
    xValues = new ArrayList<Double>();
    yValues = new ArrayList<Double>();
    int colors = Color.BLUE;

    // Initialize the XYMultipleSeriesRenderer class with line color blue
    renderer = buildRenderer(colors);

    int length = renderer.getSeriesRendererCount();

    // Assigning color area under the line graph
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        FillOutsideLine fill = new FillOutsideLine(
                FillOutsideLine.Type.BOUNDS_ALL);
        fill.setColor(Color.parseColor("#81DAF5"));
        ((XYSeriesRenderer) renderer.getSeriesRendererAt(i))
                .addFillOutsideLine(fill);

    }

    // Set the chart with x level and y level titles and renderer
    setChartSettings(renderer, "X-Y Line Chart", "", "", 0, 12, 0, 10,
            Color.LTGRAY, Color.parseColor("#81DAF5"));
    renderer.setXLabels(0);
    //renderer.addXTextLabel(20, "month");
    renderer.setYLabels(0);
    renderer.setShowGrid(true);
    renderer.setXLabelsAlign(Align.CENTER);
    renderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.RIGHT);
    renderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);
    renderer.setPanLimits(new double[] { 0, 12, 0, 11 });
    renderer.setZoomLimits(new double[] { 0, 12, 0, 10 });
    renderer.setZoomRate((float) 1.5);
    renderer.setMarginsColor(Color.parseColor("#FFEDED"));
    renderer.setXLabelsColor(Color.BLACK);
    renderer.setYLabelsColor(0, Color.BLACK);
    renderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
    renderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FBFBFC"));

    // Getting x and y axis text levels from database
    Cursor cursor1 = db.getAllXYFromDb();
    if (cursor1 != null) {
        AppZoyDebug.lOG("cursor1cursor1 ", " " + cursor1.getColumnCount());
        cursor1.moveToFirst();
        int axislength = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.xmonths).length;
        for (int k = 0; k < axislength; k++) {
            renderer.addXTextLabel(k,
                    getResources().getStringArray(R.array.xmonths)[k]);
            xValues.add(cursor1.getDouble(1));
            yValues.add(cursor1.getDouble(2));
            cursor1.moveToNext();
        }
        axislength = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.ypercent).length;
        for (int k = 0; k < axislength; k++) {
            renderer.addYTextLabel(k + 1,
                    getResources().getStringArray(R.array.ypercent)[k]);
            cursor1.moveToNext();
        }
        if (!cursor1.isClosed()) {
            cursor1.close();
        }

    }
    if (mChartView == null) {

        // initializing GraphicalView class by giving x and y coordinates
        // and the renderer variable
        mChartView = ChartFactory.getLineChartView(this,
                mDataset("", xValues, yValues), renderer);
        layout.addView(mChartView, new LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

    } else {
        mChartView.repaint();
    }

    mChartView.addZoomListener(new ZoomListener() {
          public void zoomApplied(ZoomEvent e) {

              if(e.isZoomIn())
              {
            double start = renderer.getXAxisMin();
            double stop = renderer.getXAxisMax();
            double step = (stop - start);
          //  renderer.clearXTextLabels();
            int j=0;
            for (double i = start; i <= stop; i += step) {
                renderer.removeXTextLabel(i);

             // renderer.addXTextLabel(i, ""+j++);


    /*renderer.setXAxisMin(start);
    renderer.setXAxisMax(stop);
    renderer.setPanLimits(new double[] { 0, 30 * 12, 0, 40 });
    renderer.setZoomLimits(new double[] { 0, 30* 12, 0, 40 });
           int constant1 = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < 30 * 12; k++) {

                if (k % 30 == 0) {
                    constant1 = k / 30;
                    renderer.addXTextLabel(k, getResources()
                            .getStringArray(R.array.xmonths)[k / 30]);
                } else {
                    if (k >= 30) {
                        renderer.addXTextLabel(k, k
                                - (30 * constant1) + "");

                    } else {
                        renderer.addXTextLabel(k, k + "");
                    }
                }
            } */
                }
              }
          }

          public void zoomReset() {
          }
        }, true, true);


    /*mChartView.addPanListener(new PanListener() {

        @Override
        public void panApplied() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            double start = renderer.getXAxisMin();
            double stop = renderer.getXAxisMax();
            double step = (stop - start) /12;

            for (double i = start; i <= stop; i += step) {
                 renderer.removeXTextLabel(i);
              renderer.addXTextLabel(i, "1");
            }

        }
    });*/
}

private void setChartSettings(XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer3,
        String title, String xTitle, String yTitle, double xMin,
        double xMax, double yMin, double yMax, int axesColor,
        int labelsColor) {
    renderer3.setChartTitle(title);
    renderer3.setXTitle(xTitle);
    renderer3.setYTitle(yTitle);
    renderer3.setXAxisMin(xMin);
    renderer3.setXAxisMax(xMax);
    renderer3.setYAxisMin(yMin);
    renderer3.setYAxisMax(yMax);
    renderer3.setAxesColor(axesColor);
    renderer3.setLabelsColor(labelsColor);

}

private XYMultipleSeriesRenderer buildRenderer(int colors) {
    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
    setRenderer(renderer, colors);
    return renderer;
}

// setting level text size and title text size
private void setRenderer(XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer2, int colors) {
    renderer2.setAxisTitleTextSize(16);
    renderer2.setChartTitleTextSize(20);
    renderer2.setLabelsTextSize(15);
    XYSeriesRenderer r = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    r.setColor(colors);
    renderer2.addSeriesRenderer(r);
}

private XYMultipleSeriesDataset mDataset(String titles,
        List<Double> xValues2, List<Double> yValues2) {
    XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset1 = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
    addXYSeries(dataset1, titles, xValues2, yValues2, 0);
    return dataset1;
}

private void addXYSeries(XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset, String titles,
        List<Double> xValues2, List<Double> yValues2, int scale) {

    Double[] xV = xValues2.toArray(new Double[xValues2.size()]);
    XYSeries series = new XYSeries(titles, scale);
    Double[] yV = yValues2.toArray(new Double[yValues2.size()]);
    int seriesLength = xV.length;
    for (int k = 0; k < seriesLength; k++) {
        series.add(xV[k], yV[k]);
    }
    dataset.addSeries(series);

}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    db.close();
}
```

}`

Answer (score 0):

You can start the displayed chart using custom text X axis labels for months:

```
renderer.addXTextLabel(x, "month");
```

You can listen for zoom events this way:

```
// an example of handling the zoom events on the chart
mChartView.addZoomListener(new ZoomListener() {
  public void zoomApplied(ZoomEvent e) {
    String type = "out";
    if (e.isZoomIn()) {
      type = "in";
    }
    Log.i("Zoom", "Zoom " + type + " rate " + e.getZoomRate());
  }

  public void zoomReset() {
    Log.i("Zoom", "Reset");
  }
}, true, true);
```

Then, inside the `zoomApplied` method, you could remove the existing X axis custom labels and add new ones for days.

```
renderer.removeXTextLabel(x);
renderer.addXTextLabel(anotherX, "day");
```

Comment: hey dan...i updated my code..can u plz help me...Still now i m not able to get the nested x-axis level..

Comment: Under the zoom event you are just removing the start and stop labels so far. You updated the code, but you didn't update the question. What is not working?

Comment: Hey dan you can check,i uploaded the graph screen.Actually here i am facing the problem is i gave these 2 lines `  renderer.setPanLimits(new double[] { 0, 12, 0, 10 });
renderer.setZoomLimits(new double[] { 0, 12, 0, 10 });` but it is not working properly...you can see there the x-axis levels "jan".there is a space between x-axis starting point to "jan".I want to start from jan only.But when i am tapping zoomout the images looks like this...which i don't want..can u plz help me..

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: i want there should no white space ..means from the coordinate(0,0) i want to give that background color sky..but hare "jan" is starting from lets say coordinates (1,0)..so how i can place jan in 0,0 position.So that even if i ll zoomout then there will be no change...